# Using machine learning to detect trend reversal in a time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series-analysis

I'm starting to learn machine learning, and have honed in on a problem to get my hands dirty with: how to detect a trend reversal in a time series.

[image: Trend reversal example]

I've [asked this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239868/detecting-trend-reversal-in-a-time-series) on stats.SE more than a year ago, but now I'm looking for a machine learning approach. How would I go about this specific problem vs. generally [identifying patterns in time-series data](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57830/machine-learning-identify-patterns-in-time-series-data)?

Comment: It looks like you already asked this question on Statistics.SE, and got an answer there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/239868/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Also, if you already got an answer, you should describe the suggestions you've already got and explain whether they met your needs or not and why, so people don't waste their time telling you something you already know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Stats.SE.

Comment: @D.W. - I had indeed posted the question on Cross Validated over a year ago, but now I'm looking for an ML-oriented approach.

Comment: Why?  What's wrong with the approaches you've already been given?  If you've rejected the approaches suggested there I'm worried you might just reject any approach we suggest, too.  If you rejected their approaches that's presumably because you have some requirement that they didn't meet.  If so, please edit your question to state your requirements, and state what approaches you considered (and what approaches have been suggested to you)  and why you rejected them.  The question needs to specify how you plan to evaluate proposed solutions, so we can evaluate them too.

Comment: Just re-posting the same question without indicating you've posted it before and gotten some other answers is problematic -- it risks people duplicating answers you've already gotten, which would waste your time and theirs.  You should be summarizing and linking to all related resources you've found (including the prior question you asked) and giving a little overview of the subject and how they do/don't meet your needs.  Try to make your question useful for others and show your work so far.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Have you followed [my suggestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection) and tried reading the literature on changepoint detection?  What are your reactions so far?  Is it what you are looking for?  If not, can you edit the question to explain your problem with more specificity and explain why those approaches aren't suitable here?