# machine learning classification with financial instrument/time series data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series-analysis

I am new to machine learning and have started brainstorming some model ideas that involve financial instrument/time series data. I was thinking it might be useful to use a classification algorithm to predict if an instrument was in fact up or down y% (TRUE/FALSE) after n days, based on i.e. a combination of technical indicator states for each learning example.

That said, in researching the idea I came upon an article that stated training examples in time series data are not independent of each other:

*"Time series data has a natural temporal ordering - this differs from typical data mining/machine learning applications where each data point is an independent example of the concept to be learned, and the ordering of data points within a data set does not matter"*

My question is as follows: is the above true only if we are trying to predict the continuous value of an asset n days into the future? As far as my idea outlined in the first paragraph is concerned, would this then still be valid considering I am not (apparently) taking into account the specific relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that:

- a "sliding window" approach can be used with any *standard* regression / classification algorithm. E.g. given the following time series

  ```
  Time High Low Open Close Volume
    1   H1   L1  O1   C1     V1
    2   H2   L2  O2   C2     V2
    ...
    i   Hi   Li  Oi   Ci     Vi
  ```

  you can feed the ML algorithm with these examples:

  ```
    O0, H1, L1, O1, C1, V1, H2, L2, O2, C2, V2, H3, L3, O3, C3, V3
    O1, H2, L2, O2, C2, V2, H3, L3, O3, C3, V3, H4, V4, O4, C4, V4
    O2, H3, L3, O3, C3, V3, H4, V4, O4, C4, V4, H5, V5, O5, C5, V5
    ...
  ```

  (the first value is the target)

  The size of the window (`s`) is an important limitation: the algorithm cannot correlate "[candles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart)" that lie more than `s` timesteps apart.

  On the other end, with a large `s`, all examples appear to be sparse and dissimilar in many ways (see [Curse of dimensionality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)).

  You may use other features (e.g. averages, multiple timeframes, Japanese candlestick patterns...) but not without a good knowledge of the specific domain.
- ML has tools that, in theory, can deal with timeseries. E.g. [Recurrent neural networks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) can take advantage of their internal memory to process arbitrary sequences of inputs and exhibit dynamic temporal behavior. See [Which machine learning algorithms can be used for time series forecasts?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13937/50003) for references.

Comment: Neural networks seem like overkill. Linear mixed models can capture non-independence between samples.